# Why am I getting the error "undefined method `name' for" in a Formtastic / haml view where "name" is a property on the model?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, haml, formtastic

This is probably something stupid, but I don't know nearly enough about rails & ruby to see it. I have the following schema & view but I am getting the error mentioned below. Business inherits from a Devise Account so thats where the email & password come from.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**schema:**

```
  create_table "businesses", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "street"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

**View:**

```
#registrationForm
  -semantic_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url=> registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
    =f.input :name
    =f.input :email
    =f.input :password
    =f.input :password_confirmation
    =f.buttons
```

**Error:**

```
undefined method 'name' for
<Business:0x000000052690f8 > Extracted source (around line #3):
```

---

## Edit

**Controller**

```
class BusinessesController < Devise::RegistrationsController 
  respond_to :html
   def new
     super
     @business = Business.new
   end
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
  devise_for :accounts 
  devise_for :businesses, :controllers => { :registrations => "businesses" }
```

**Model**

```
class Business < Account 
end
```

**console after reloading schema**

```
k = Business.new ( :name =>"test" )
                          ^
(irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting $end
    from /home/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /home/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/chance/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: @fl00r I added both the controller and the routes.rb

Comment: `undefined method 'name' for` for what?

Comment: @fl00r sorry, looks like it was gobbled up by formatting. Its  #<Business:0x00000003fbeac0>

Comment: Hope your've executed all migrations?

Comment: Yep, there are only 2 models (account & business)

Comment: the db was created with both in existence too

Comment: try run something like: `b = Business.new( :name => "Test" )` in your Rails console (to open it `rails c`)

Comment: Hmm, its returning the below.  I don't see my properties don't seem to be there.
#<Business id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "", password_salt: "", reset_password_token: nil, remember_token: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Comment: just in case I did the inheritance wrong, I added the 2 loc for model.

Comment: you can try to force load your schema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a table named 'accounts' and a table named 'businesses'.

Account is being made by devise, and has all its attributes, and points to the 'accounts' table.
Business inherits from Account, and therefore is using Rails' STI ([single table inheritance](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html)) features. It therefore points to the 'accounts' table as well.

If you were to have `Business < ActiveRecord::Base` it would point to your 'businesses' table. ActiveRecord's STI mechanism is very strange.

I think you need to think more about how you want your data model to work. Perhaps Business should `belong_to :account` and have an according :account_id.

Either that or you could add all the 'businesses' columns to the accounts table.

Comment: Ah ha, okay that kind of (but not really) makes sense to me. This kind of leaves me with a model that I wanted but wasn't sure how to go about doing it.

If I create a Devise Account outside of its workflow (in this case, it'll be through Business), how do I ensure that the workflow continues after the fact?

Comment: By workflow, do you mean, 'emails get sent'? If so, I believe Devise will send them when the account object is created whether you do so from within its controllers or your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to load your schema again

```
rake db:schema:load
```

Comment: Well, that got me one step closer. Following your advise about using the console, I got an error (posting it in the edit above).

Comment: it looks like there may be a problem with a gem or something.. ugh. You've helped enough man. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: reread my comment above, didn't mean for to potentially sound snobbish. I just meant that I didn't want to take up anymore of your time and I appreciated your help. Thanks again.